# Скрипт Centos на создание пользователя-админа

Tags: linux, centos

создать в CentOS пользователя, который может обслуживать сервисы приложения и докера, но не имеет доступа к папке с файлами opt/sce/data/storage, как сделать это скриптом?

Comment: Читали `man useradd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Cоздайте группу, если её нет

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

Добавьте пользователя в группу

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Перелогиньтесь и попробуйте запустить докер без sudo

```
$ docker run hello-world
```